# How should the order of faculty names be in a letter?

Tags: faculty-application, application-cover-letter

Assume we have 6 professors with names that are:

> Professor: David Goh and Gautam George
>   Associate Professor: Juan James and Laura Alfaro
>   Assistant Professor: Abigail Baldwin and Jose Choudhury

How should the names of faculty members be ordered in an application or cover letter (previous or potential collaborators)? First order by rank and then order by last name? Or just by last name.

1. George, Goh, James, Alfaro, Baldwin, and Choudhury
2. Alfaro, Baldwin, Choudhury, George, Goh, and James

Comment: Can you use names that are easier to memorise, please, e.g., Alice Bobson, Carl Doe, … Also, what kind of letter are we talking about?

Comment: Any letter, including cover letter

Comment: Wait, why have you ordered the names as you have?  I will assume the second "Associate" is a typo for "Assistant", but why aren't you introducing your arbitrary variables in alphabetical order within the ranks?!?

Comment: "Any letter, including cover letter" That's not a very helpful response.  There is no preferred ordering independent of the context.  If you're writing an introductory paragraph in a letter to your parents in which you're going to talk about your professors, order them in the order you talk about them (if you like).  Or if you're writing to your friends, order them in a way which seems most amusing (if you like): Cox, Zucker rather than Zucker, Cox.

Comment: The 3rd is assistant.

Comment: A little bit of context (i.e. the sentence before and after this list of names) would help clarify this question, since right now I'm having trouble understanding why anyone would ever need to include a list of six names in a letter...

Comment: @ff524: At least in my field, when people apply for a faculty position, they (more) often (than not) include in their cover letter a list of names of faculty that they think would be interested in their work.  Among other things, this is an indication that the application should be showed to these faculty members even if they are not on the relevant admissions committee (which is often a small subset of the faculty).

Comment: @ff524 Can be an application letter or cover letter

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I have added more details

Comment: FYI, your 1. is not a correct instance of ordering first by rank and then by last name.  (I don't see why you need examples at all, but your presentation of them certainly makes your question more confusing.)

Comment: Better, but you really shouldn’t use the names of actual persons.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft they are random names

Comment: @Pete L. Clark I have seen # 1. been used so, I wonder if its right or 2. is better

Comment: @Thomas: This is getting a bit tedious.  #1 is not a correct instance of what you said in your question was the first option: namely, ordering first by rank and then by last name.  As to which of 1 and 2 is actually better: I already answered that question.

Comment: @ThomasLee: I may underestimate the chances, but [they do not appear that random](https://www.google.de/search?q=David+Goh+Gautam+George+Juan+James+Laura+Alfaro+Abigail+Baldwin+Jose+Choudhury).

Comment: You should also clarify why previous collaborators and potential collaborators appear on the same list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the choice of tags, I think you mean a cover letter for a job application.  In that context, I suppose you are giving names of faculty that you want to work with and/or have a research connection with.  (It couldn't hurt to make this more explicit in your question.)  Assuming that:

Ordering the faculty by rank doesn't make a lot of sense to me.  Alphabetical order is perfectly reasonable and common.  However, the more names you list without any commentary, the more it looks like you are fishing for something rather than calling attention to a real kinship or commonality.  Thus, if you are going to list more than one or two names, it would be a better idea to break it up into several sentences and describe what you think the intellectual relations are.  If you do this, you should group by the type of connection you have -- e.g. "Professors X and Y may be interested in my work on perverse sheaves" -- and it would make sense to list the strongest connections first.

If you just give a list of names out of alphabetical order, it's not clear what the ordering means.  (In fact you do so in the statement of the question: within the faculty ranks, your variable names are not alphabetized.  Once I noticed that, I found it very confusing.  That may be useful information for you.)  Two possibilities: (i) The names are listed in descending order of importance (somehow).  (ii) You wrote the letter very quickly and just grabbed names in the order you found them.  Nobody likes to be ranked down in importance without understanding why, so I wouldn't do this.

**Added**: The above answer is from the perspective of an American university.  Maybe academic rank is taken more seriously as a form of social rank in other cultures (it really isn't in the US: a new hire assistant professor calls all her colleagues by their first names immediately on arrival).  If by chance you are applying to a university in Asia, then I wouldn't assume this answer applies.

Comment: I'll say it more plainly: **Ordering the faculty by rank doesn't make sense** (at least in the US).

Comment: In parts of Europe (at least the Nordic countries) it also makes no sense. As Pete mentions, in the US newly hired assistant professors are on a first name basis with the other faculty. Here, you are generally on a first name basis with any faculty you speak with on a regular basis, even as a first-year student. (It took me a while to get used to the PhD students calling the faculty "professor lastname" or "doctor lastname" while I was at UGA).